# Why does qwindows.dll from Qt5.0.2 cause my application to crash

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt5

We are deploying a Qt5.0.2 application built with VS2010 that includes the `platforms/qwindows.dll` file in the bin directory.  We just upgraded from Qt5.0.1 to Qt5.0.2 and discovered that on non-development machines our application was crashing immediately after loading.  We narrowed the problem down to the qwindows.dll file.  When we use the qwindows.dll version from Qt5.0.2 (file size 803kb) the application crashes.  When we leave all other included dlls the same but replace only qwindows.dll with the 5.0.1 version (799kb), everything works.  Is this a known bug?  Is there something else that we need to include for the 5.0.2 version of the dll to work?

Comment: Yes.  When debugging, as soon as I create an instance of QApplication, I get 'Failed to load platform plugin "windows": Available platforms are: windows'.  Then the application exits with code 1.

Comment: check with dependency walker if qwindows.dll requires further DLLs that not there.

Comment: Already checked... The only thing missing is IESHIMS.DLL which I've always succesfully ignored in the past.  I'm trying to use depends.exe profiling to see what happens when QApplication gets created, but it freezes up before I reach that point.

Comment: Misunderstood your previous post.  I now checked qwindows.dll in depends.  It requires icudt49.dll, icuin49.dll, icuuc49.dll, libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll.  All of these are in the bin directory (which contains the platforms directory that qwindows.dll is in) with the exes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

We had a batch script that automatically copied the relevant prebuilt qt dlls into our application's installation directory from subdirectories of the latest downloaded qt package's `vs2010` directory.  It appears that in Qt5.0.1, Qt dlls appeared in both the `lib` and `bin` subdirectories of `msvc2010`, whereas in Qt5.0.2, the Qt dlls appear only in the `bin` subdirectory.  Since we were automatically copying dlls from the `lib` subdirectory, when we migrated to 5.0.2 nothing was copied and the old 5.0.1 dlls remained in our application's installation directory.  The `qwindows.dll` file, however, is still located in `msvc2010\plugins\platforms` and so that did get updated and was not compatible with the old 5.0.1 dlls.

I don't think that we did anything funny with the downloaded Qt installations, but I would certainly appreciate if someone else who has downloaded both 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 could independently verify that 5.0.1 has dlls in the `msvc2010\lib directory` and 5.0.2 doesn't.